# Passing row values from Spark df to functions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
val someDF = Seq(
  (8, "abc"),
  (64, "sdf"),
  (-27, "yui")
).toDF("number", "word")

def numberValidation(numberValidation:Any): Boolean=
numberValidation match{
case int :Integer => true
case _ => false}

def wordValidatoin(wordValidation:Any): Boolean=
wordValidation match{
case str: String => true
case _ => false}
```

I need to pass each row with its coressponding values to the mentioned functions.
Value of number column in first row = 8 which is passed to numbervalidation and word column in first row is abc passed to wordValidatoin

Answer (score 0):

Use spark [UDF](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-scalar.html) and change your method as below :

```
  val numberValidation = udf((numberValidation: Any) => {
     numberValidation match{
    case int :Integer => true
    case _ => false
    }
  })
  
 

val wordValidatoin = udf((wordValidation:Any)): =>{
    wordValidation match{
    case str: String => true
    case _ => false
    }
})
```

and check with DF as below :

```
someDF
.withColumn("checkNum",numberValidation($"number"))
.withColumn("checWord",wordValidatoin($"word"))
.show
```